# heyzapp cordova plugin with third party sdk's not working for ios and android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, mobile-ad-mediation, heyzap

We have to integrate heyzapp mediation in ionic based application with third party sdk like vungle, admob, unity ads etc.. We have followed each and every line which has been mentioned in the doc but the problem is that we are getting errors.

For eg. NO SDK detected
NO Network Found

We are struggling with this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you have any errors in console?

Comment: show me you code also

Comment: No errors are not coming in console.

Comment: NO SDK detected NO Network Found - we are getting these errors

Can you let us know step by step implementation ?